# How to write MySQL Query in Laravel 5 without using PHP String function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to eliminate the specific prefix of a string by default on getting value from the database.

In MySQL, i can use the following,

```
SELECT RIGHT('abc3',1) -- Results in "3"
SELECT RIGHT('abc3',2) -- Results in "c3"
```

But, how can i use same process in Laravel eloquent?.

Or any other solutions are available for remove the prefix of a string while retrieve from database in laravel.

I know trim will eliminate, but only spaces.

```
ex.
 property_color
 property_size
```

Here i need to extract "**property_**".

```
expect.
  color
  size
```

Is it possible in laravel, in **without using PHP String function**.

Only on Direct eloquent Operation.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Same query use in `DB::raw`

Comment: `$someVariable = Input::get("some_variable");

$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = '$someVariable'") );` This is just example of query

Comment: Can't you just do a normal query then select the chunk of the string you need with PHP's `substr()` function?

Comment: what happened if i process with huge amount of records ?
Instead of using external operations("substr"), Internal will improve performance right ?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would do:

```
 $arrayData = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT RIGHT('abc3',1) ")):
```

you can pass array of parameter to bind values:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("  SQL QUERY  "),$paramsArray);
```

Comment: But, this comes under the Query Builder, here relational model get rejected. That's why i looking forward of Elaquent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use raw queries within your builder like

```
$results = YourRepo::where(DB::raw("SELECT SUBSTRING('property_color',9)") , 'LIKE', "%property_xxx%");
```

keep in mind that substring is slow.

Comment: But this will not allow me to do Eloquent Relationships, Right ?